# Enumerating 1-Lipschitz functions on an integer grid

Tags: covering, euclidean-lattices

Let $G$ denote an integer grid consisting of $\{0,\dots,m\}\times\{0,\dots,n\}$.  An integer-valued function  $f:G\to\mathbb{Z}$ is said to be *1-Lipschitz* if it satisfies $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq \| x-y \|$ for all $x,y\in G$.  My question is:  what is an upper bound for the total number of functions $f$ of this kind, if we assume that $f(0,0)$ is fixed?

If we were in one dimension instead of two, this would be obvious:  from each point $x$ to $x+1$, we have $f(x)-f(x+1)\in \{-1,0,1\}$, thus the total number of functions would be $3^m$.

Comment: A few special cases are in the OEIS: $m=1$ is 
https://oeis.org/A138977 , $m=2$ is https://oeis.org/A138978 , $m=3$ is https://oeis.org/A138979 , and $m=n$ is https://oeis.org/A068748 .